# Slice xarray when latitude and longitude are 2 D

Tags: python-xarray

If I have this xarray

```
ds = xr.tutorial.open_dataset("rasm").load()
```

we have

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (time: 36, y: 205, x: 275)
Coordinates:
  * time     (time) object 1980-09-16 12:00:00 ... 1983-08-17 00:00:00
    xc       (y, x) float64 189.2 189.4 189.6 189.7 ... 17.65 17.4 17.15 16.91
    yc       (y, x) float64 16.53 16.78 17.02 17.27 ... 28.26 28.01 27.76 27.51
Dimensions without coordinates: y, x
Data variables:
    Tair     (time, y, x) float64 nan nan nan nan nan ... 29.8 28.66 28.19 28.21
...
```

So, `xc`, which is longitude, is a matrix 205x275. Similar for `yc`.

I want to subselect, for the first date, a matrix of data between `xc=(150, 40)` and `yc=(19, 23)`. If `xc` and `yc` were 1 D, it would be something like

```
ds_sel = ds.sel(time="1980-09-16", xc=slice(150,40), yc=slice(19,23))
```

but this doesn't work for 2 dimensional arrays like this case. What should I do? Can coordinates and data variables be flattened someway? Thx.

Comment: you could use `.where(conditions, drop=True)` to limit the extent of the data to be within these bounds. but since your data is not a rectangle in lat/lon, the resulting values will be an irregular shape in x/y space, with NaNs anywhere the condition is not met for that x/y pair, even after cropping the data to only include coordinates where x or y have at least some valid data.

Comment: you cannot simply flatten the coordinates... the relationship between x, y and lat/lon is nonlinear and multivariate, period. you could regrid and transform the data using a tool like xESMF, but it will involve interpolating to the new coordinates.